# extracting xml value with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

Let have the following XML:

```
<rest:RESTResponse xmlns:rest="http://schemas.activebpel.org/REST/2007/12/01/aeREST.xsd"
                   statusCode="200">
   <rest:headers>
      <rest:header name="Date" value="Sun,10 Feb 2019 13:46:02 GMT"/>
      <rest:header name="Transfer-Encoding" value="chunked"/>
      <rest:header name="Content-Type" value="text/xml;charset=utf-8"/>
      <rest:header name="Server" value="Apache-Coyote/1.1"/>
   </rest:headers>
   <rest:payload contentType="text/xml">
      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <soapenv:Body>
            <getBatchGroupStatusReturn xmlns="urn:siperian.api">
               <rowidBatchGroupLog>SVR1.ENYY</rowidBatchGroupLog>
               <batchGroupUid>BATCH_GROUP.BPD_STAGE</batchGroupUid>
               <startRunDate>2019-02-10T14:46:02.157+01:00</startRunDate>
               <runStatus>2</runStatus>
            </getBatchGroupStatusReturn>
         </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>
   </rest:payload>
</rest:RESTResponse>
```

How I can extract the value of the "runStatus" element? I tried the following path:

```
rest:RESTResponse/rest:payload/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/getBatchGroupStatusReturn/runStatus
```

, but this is working only if I removed the xmlns="urn:siperian.api" from a parent element. But I can't do any change in the response which I received.

Comment: Not sure what you're using to execute the xpath, but most of the time you can register namespace prefixes, so that you can use `sip:getBatchGroupStatusReturn` for example. Could you check if thats available?

Comment: thanks. I defined the new namespace with that URN and now when I modified my xpath it is working like: rest:RESTResponse/rest:payload/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/sip:getBatchGroupStatusReturn/sip:runStatus